# how to create a json object in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I want to post value in json format to server but i am stuck with the json format. I have searched alot on google but still didnt get the exact format.

```
{

    "accountId": "14",
    "order_items": [
        {
        "item_id": "5",
        "quantity": "4 Kg",
        "price": " 69.99"
       },
       {

        "item_id": "6",
        "quantity": "6 Kg",
        "price": " 79.99"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried the following code:

```
NSDictionary *dict=@{@"item_id" : itemide,
                     @"quantity" : @"10",
                     @"price" : @"100"};


NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"accountId" : @"14",
                             @"order_items" : dict};

NSError *error;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:&error];

if (error)
    NSLog(@"Failure to serialize JSON object %@", error);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.lococo.in/orders"];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                           timeoutInterval:180.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"AGDHFGH243SFS" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-User"];
[request setValue:@"abcgdg#dg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Please help me with it. How do it get it in above format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing that order_items is an array.

```
NSDictionary* item1 = @{ @"item_id": @"5", @"quantity": @"4 Kg", @"price": @" 69.99" };
NSDictionary* item2 = @{ @"item_id": @"6", @"quantity": @"6 Kg", @"price": @"79.99" };

NSArray* orderItems = @[item1, item2];
NSDictionary* order = @{ @"accountId": @"24", @"order_items": orderItems };
```

And that's what you pass to NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSDictionary *dict=@{@"item_id" : itemide,
                     @"quantity" : @"10",
                     @"price" : @"100"};
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"accountId" : @"14",
                             @"order_items" : dict};
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Comment: How can i use it to get multiple values

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the value of dictionary how a array.

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *dict=@{@"item_id" : itemide,
                    @"quantity" : @"10",
                       @"price" : @"100"};


NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = @{@"accountId" : @"14"};
[dictionary setObject:arrayContainer forKey:@"order_items"];

NSMutableArray *arrayContainer = [NSMutableArray array];
[arrayContainer addObject:dict];
```

Comment: can u tell me what id providerDic coz wen i tried ur code it crashed on setObject